# Rails 4 Route Friendly URL to Query URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, url-routing

I feel this is should be easy but I'm stuck. What's the best way to map a route and have it point to specific url?

User types/click http://acne.com/category-name and it will get http://acne.com/?category[]=1

I don't want to redirect to **?category[]=1** though. I want to make it SEO friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to show the category when user types in acne.com/category-name.

Add this in your config/routes.rb:

get '/:category-name', to: 'category#show'

This will route the request to your categoryController's show method with the user-typed category name in the "category-name" parameter. You can handle what is displayed there (use params[:category-name] to find out the category name the user has typed in)

Sorry for the lack of code tags, I'm on mobile.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I understand this method. I guess i'm being lazy and didn't want to create a new controller but this is probably faster route than wasting anymore time.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem.

Here is an example o how it could work:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name
end

@category = Category.friendly.find "category-name"   
@category.to_param
redirect_to @category # the URL will be /category/category-name
```